# On Page Load Offset Value set to 0. On Inspection value is calculated

Tags: javascript, jquery, less, race-condition

The goal is to use a url fragid to jump to a particular section on a separate page on page load. `<a href="page.php#section>`

The unexpected behavior is that on page load the offsetTop does not seem to get calculated or the value gets overwritten.

- When I call `console.log($("#section").offset());`
- from a `<script>` tag of the loaded PHP file,
- or a linked js file calling at `jQuery(document).ready(function() {})`,
- or `$(window).on('load', function() {})`

all result in a console log of `{ top: 0, left:0 }`.

However once the file is loaded, I manually open Dev Tools and enter `console.log($("#section").offset());` and it returns the expected output of `{ top:200px, left: 200px }`. 
 - When I load the page without calling the LESS file the calculation happens. This leads me to believe that it is a race condition with LESS. However this seems strange that LESS would be fighting and overwriting a html:5 function.

Comment: If possible, you shouldn't use the browser-based `less.min.js` in any production situation. Instead use the command-line tool to precompile your LESS to CSS and serve that.

Comment: I million percent agree. Its a legacy workflow process and is not how this should be used. I'm not trying to blame LESS for this problem. But I am more interested in the clarification as to the mystery of this unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append a simple URI query component to the value of the `href` attribute of your anchor.

```
<a href="page.php?hash=section">Click here</a>
```

Then, add code on `page.php` to handle the URI query in the `GET` request.

```
<!-- at bottom of markup just before end body -->
<?php if (@$_GET['hash'] === 'section') echo '<script>window.location.hash="section";</script>'; ?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

with javascript

```js
window.onload = function (){
  "use strict";
document.body.addEventListener("load",function(){
    // your code here   
 });
}
```

with jquery it's easy

```js
$("body").on("load",function(){
  // here code
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The document body load still loads before the style resets the element's calculated position.